# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.13.12

Tags: api-platform.com

Since yesterday I have a " 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.13.12". I don't know how to proceed to fix the problem. I'm using API-platform 2.2.5 with docker and everything was working fine on monday. I was working on the react part of my project (front part) and didn't touch to the php part.

I'm not really a developer, I'm cardiologist so please be indulgent

I'm in localhost. here is the docker-compose configuration:

```html
version: '3.4'

services:
  php:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_php
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/php
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    # Comment out these volumes in production
    volumes:
      - ./api:/srv/api:rw,cached
      # If you develop on Linux, uncomment the following line to use a bind-mounted host directory instead
      # - ./api/var:/srv/api/var:rw

  api:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_nginx
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    # Comment out this volume in production
    volumes:
      - ./api/public:/srv/api/public:ro
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  cache-proxy:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    build:
      context: ./api
      target: api_platform_varnish
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/varnish
    depends_on:
      - api
    volumes:
      - ./api/docker/varnish/conf:/usr/local/etc/varnish:ro
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  db:
    # In production, you may want to use a managed database service
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=api
      - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  client:
    # Use a static website hosting service in production
    # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    build:
      context: ./client
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/client
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/client:rw,cached
      - /usr/src/client/node_modules
    ports:
      - "80:3000"

  admin:
    # Use a static website hosting service in production
    # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/admin
    build:
      context: ./admin
      cache_from:
        - ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/admin
    env_file:
      - ./admin/.env
    volumes:
      - ./admin:/usr/src/admin:rw,cached
      - /usr/src/admin/node_modules
    ports:
      - "81:3000"

  h2-proxy:
    # Don't use this proxy in prod
    build:
      context: ./h2-proxy
    depends_on:
      - client
      - admin
      - api
      - cache-proxy
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "444:444"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8444:8444"

volumes:
  db-data: {}
```

And here is the "docker ps -a"

```html
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                                                    NAMES
b8afc6d88f5c        apiplatform225_h2-proxy        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:443-444->443-444/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443-8444->8443-8444/tcp   apiplatform225_h2-proxy_1
d27a612304f0        quay.io/api-platform/varnish   "docker-app-start"       2 hours ago         Exited (255) 2 hours ago                                                                             apiplatform225_cache-proxy_1
edcc73e05921        quay.io/api-platform/nginx     "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp                                                     apiplatform225_api_1
ee7b51f67258        postgres:9.6-alpine            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                                              apiplatform230_db_1
0caf11454e02        quay.io/api-platform/client    "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                                              apiplatform230_client_1
9006a7666a5c        quay.io/api-platform/admin     "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   2 hours ago         Created                                                                                              apiplatform230_admin_1
280c7ffd16e9        quay.io/api-platform/php       "docker-entrypoint p…"   2 hours ago         Exited (2) 2 hours ago                                                                               apiplatform225_php_1
0b49a51052a3        postgres:9.6-alpine            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                                   apiplatform225_db_1
184992869a9e        fhirbase/fhirbase              "/usr/lib/postgresql…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                              fhirbase
682bf87a0fc5        3e44013e9186                   "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get…"   2 months ago        Exited (100) 2 months ago                                                                            blissful_pasteur
940f8855a5bb        quay.io/api-platform/client    "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   2 months ago        Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:82->3000/tcp                                                     apiplatform225_client_1
9cadfc1382c4        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                              serene_minsky
12f21ccb34b7        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 months ago        Created                                                                                              test-nginx
37ebd4a37d22        quay.io/api-platform/admin     "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   2 months ago        Up 2 hours                  0.0.0.0:81->3000/tcp                                                     apiplatform225_admin_1
d9bfd09120ab        apiplatform_app                "docker-app-entrypoi…"   8 months ago        Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform_app_1
1881c977d54a        apiplatform_nginx              "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   8 months ago        Created                                                                                              apiplatform_nginx_1
e243b33c5ca3        apiplatform_db                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 months ago        Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform_db_1
e4825a696db2        apiplatform211_varnish         "docker-app-start"       9 months ago        Exited (137) 8 months ago                                                                            apiplatform211_varnish_1
a5175efdbc0e        apiplatform211_app             "docker-app-entrypoi…"   9 months ago        Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform211_app_1
2ac32603ceec        apiplatform211_nginx           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 months ago        Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform211_nginx_1
17a6943dfe70        apiplatform211_db              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 months ago        Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform211_db_1
```

I restarted docker on my computer, and launch "docker-compose up -d", but it don't change anything.

here is the new "docker ps -a

```html
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                        PORTS                                                                    NAMES
c18810c582dc        api-platform-225_h2-proxy      "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   58 seconds ago       Up 55 seconds                 0.0.0.0:443-444->443-444/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443-8444->8443-8444/tcp   api-platform-225_h2-proxy_1
e7c71d0a2b48        quay.io/api-platform/varnish   "docker-app-start"       59 seconds ago       Exited (255) 55 seconds ago                                                                            api-platform-225_cache-proxy_1
dd609020d56a        quay.io/api-platform/nginx     "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up 58 seconds                 0.0.0.0:8082->80/tcp                                                     api-platform-225_api_1
698223caf6e7        quay.io/api-platform/php       "docker-entrypoint p…"   About a minute ago   Exited (2) 58 seconds ago                                                                              api-platform-225_php_1
d309a24a9a8b        quay.io/api-platform/client    "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:82->3000/tcp                                                     api-platform-225_client_1
96a5d6510aa2        postgres:9.6-alpine            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                                   api-platform-225_db_1
f2899db1ec25        quay.io/api-platform/admin     "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute             0.0.0.0:81->3000/tcp                                                     api-platform-225_admin_1
ee7b51f67258        postgres:9.6-alpine            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago         Created                                                                                                apiplatform230_db_1
0caf11454e02        quay.io/api-platform/client    "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   21 hours ago         Created                                                                                                apiplatform230_client_1
9006a7666a5c        quay.io/api-platform/admin     "/bin/sh -c 'yarn st…"   21 hours ago         Created                                                                                                apiplatform230_admin_1
184992869a9e        fhirbase/fhirbase              "/usr/lib/postgresql…"   2 months ago         Created                                                                                                fhirbase
682bf87a0fc5        3e44013e9186                   "/bin/sh -c 'apt-get…"   2 months ago         Exited (100) 2 months ago                                                                              blissful_pasteur
9cadfc1382c4        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 months ago         Created                                                                                                serene_minsky
12f21ccb34b7        nginx                          "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 months ago         Created                                                                                                test-nginx
d9bfd09120ab        apiplatform_app                "docker-app-entrypoi…"   8 months ago         Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                                apiplatform_app_1
1881c977d54a        apiplatform_nginx              "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   8 months ago         Created                                                                                                apiplatform_nginx_1
e243b33c5ca3        apiplatform_db                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 months ago         Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                                apiplatform_db_1
e4825a696db2        apiplatform211_varnish         "docker-app-start"       9 months ago         Exited (137) 8 months ago                                                                              apiplatform211_varnish_1
a5175efdbc0e        apiplatform211_app             "docker-app-entrypoi…"   9 months ago         Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                                apiplatform211_app_1
2ac32603ceec        apiplatform211_nginx           "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 months ago         Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                                apiplatform211_nginx_1
17a6943dfe70        apiplatform211_db              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 months ago         Exited (0) 8 months ago                                                                                apiplatform211_db_1
```

If there is a problem with my php code how can I find it without the debug bar of symfony?

Comment: Could you explain the setup of this system I.E how frontend and backend connects? Could you also post the result of `docker ps -a` in the question as well?

Comment: Actually, ignore the first part of my question, I found that from api-platform distribution. I just need the second part.

Comment: I added the docker-compose configuration and  the "docker ps -a". I hope it will help

Comment: I thought this might be the case, as you can are container `apiplatform225_php_1` has exited with code `2`.
This is due to bug in your code or bad config. Easiest way to check is run `docker-compose up -d` again and see if the container exit with non-zero code.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean in your first phrase. I restarted docker on my computer, and launch "docker-compose up -d", but it don't change anything. If there is a problem with my php code how can I find it without the debug bar of symfony?

Comment: What I meant is, if you look at the output of the `docker ps -a`, all the processes that are `Exited` with anything other than `Exited (0)` are crashed due to some sort of error. I.E. `Exited (137)` means it ran out of memory.
So If running `docker-compose up -d` didn't work, you need to run `docker-compose down` then `docker ps -a` and if you see any process listed at all. You need to get rid of it by running `docker rm CONTAINER ID`. I.E. `docker rm d27a612304f0`. Then run `docker-compose up -d` to get fresh containers.

Comment: As per how to debug is not that simple and straightforward with this kind of complex systems. You can, however, run `docker-compose up` without `-d` so it prints everything on the terminal instead of a list of services. `-d` means run in detached (background).

Comment: I've tried to get fresh containers but it didn't change anything. So I've installed the new version of api-platform (vs 2.3) with the same code php, and react. Now it works fine. I don't really know if the version was the problem. Thanks for the help !!!

Comment: It might have been the version.